# Android adMob AdvIew requesting internet access when layout is inflated

Tags: android, admob

I have a com.google.ads.AdView in my layouts. I have a lite and pro version of my app, and the layout is hidden if the pro version is running.

The AdView is set to NOT load an add on create:

```
   <com.google.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
       ads:adSize="IAB_MRECT"
       ads:adUnitId="a15235585e60557"
       ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"
       android:gravity="bottom" />
```

However when the following line of code is called from my OnCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
```

The following error is shown in the logcat (for the pro version, which doesn't have INTERNET permissions in the manifest):

E/Ads(30709): INTERNET permissions must be enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.
E/Ads(30709): You must have INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

Now, it's not a fatal error, as the application can continue to load but it causes the load process to hang, as whatever Internet Access is taking place, is taking place on the UI thread - causing the app to hand a for a few seconds while loading. In fact I get the following message in the logcat when loading if I give the app INTERNET permissions:

I/Choreographer(30487): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Now, of course, there are various ways around this. I can think of doing the following:

- Having Separate layouts for Lite/Full version, and just having to 'make do' with the pause on the lite version
- Adding the AddView programatically, AFTER the app has loaded and displayed its initial layout. This would make it less noticeable as it's unlikely the user would want to interact with the app as soon as the screen is shown

But these are just workarounds. I'd really prefer to know WHY the layout is trying to access the internet, and how to prevent it doing so.